# Taking input from a generic usb gamepad in controllers (preferably like MSP430g2231)

Tags: usb, hid

I was just wondering how can I take input from this cheap but awesome HID compliant generic computer gamepad into the launchpad. I know the launchpad could work at good speed so what it would take to take the input? The info doesn't really have to be about only launchpad just give me generic info, I can build off that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the device is a "USB HID Device" then the system you want to build would have to act like a "USB Host".

For this you will require a microcontroller with "USB 2.0 OTG" in it (OTG = On The Go).

The little MSP430s in the launchpad don't do it.

You would need something like a PIC24 or PIC32 that has the facility, or one the Atmel chips with OTG in it.  There are probably some TI chips that do it as well, but not that will fit in the launchpad.

It's generally the higher-end chips that have that facility.

Comment: Another option would be to see how exactly the controller works. In some cases, the raw signal from the inputs may be intercepted and rerouted to an external microcontroller. The question is: Would that be easier than making a game controller from scratch or making an USB host?

Comment: @AndrejaKo that is the question I am trying to answer here, also wanted to know if USB hosts were easy (not necessarily easier)

Comment: USB hosts are some fairly tricky programming, though many people find a solution where someone else has done most of the work.  Still, they tend to start in the $30-50 range (based on chips that e are typically $10-13 in single quantity), vs. the $10-30 range for simple boards with USB client side interfaces (based on $2-$5 chips).  Taking the controller apart and wiring the controls to your own micro is probably faster and cheaper for a one off, but in production the labor would be not be cost effective unless you had them assembled with your PCB at the original factory.